# Progressdialog slow to show in Android

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm sure this is a simple threading issue but...

I'm starting a ProgressDialog using:

```
ProgressDialog.show(Example.this, " " , " Loading. Please wait ... ", true,true);
```

Then running a block of code to download and parse XML.

The problem I'm having is that this is all running under a onClick button method, and that the xml is downloaded and parsed before the dialog is shown.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly a threading issue. Threads are our friends (even if they are annoying to use). That tutorial you found is pretty nice, but I'd suggest you check out the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class... it makes life easier. There's a nice writeup on it [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html).

Comment: @Imam Marashi Both links still load for me.